# PDF.js with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf.js

I'm building a Google Docs plugin and I'm trying to pull a PDF from an external site to parse (for simple things like number of pages, text content, etc. that **doesn't require visual rendering of the document**). However, I've been having a lot of trouble integrating the Javascript library into my project.

I understand that I will have to do some manual work to remove some stuff that are the parts that are browser-dependent, like DOM rendering or network connections. However, the error here is completely unrelated.

I've tried manually copying all the source files into the project (changing the paths where required) *and* [using a "built" library I found online](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js) (as just that one file in my project). However, I'm getting an odd syntax error whenever I save my project-

> Missing name after . operator. (line 1120, file "pdf")

This is line 1120 in file "pdf":

```
if (typeof globalScope.Promise.prototype.catch !== 'function') {
```

This is a chunk of related code:

```
if (typeof globalScope.Promise.resolve !== 'function') {
  globalScope.Promise.resolve = function (value) {
    return new globalScope.Promise(function (resolve) { resolve(value); });
  };
}
if (typeof globalScope.Promise.reject !== 'function') {
  globalScope.Promise.reject = function (reason) {
    return new globalScope.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      reject(reason);
    });
  };
}
if (typeof globalScope.Promise.prototype.catch !== 'function') {
  globalScope.Promise.prototype.catch = function (onReject) {
    return globalScope.Promise.prototype.then(undefined, onReject);
  };
}
return;
```

However, no syntax errors that I can see *there.*

So, real question:

- There doesn't seem to be an apparent syntax issue. If there is one and I am overlooking that, what is that error?
- Otherwise, how can I find out where this issue originates? It seems like an odd, cascading issue.

Comment: Did you get this working in appscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `catch` is a JavaScript reserved word Apps Script is strict and blocks its use as a parameter.

Your code IS valid, just not strict mode friendly.

Use `globalScope.Promise.prototype['catch']` instead.